# MySql "WHERE" at least some value matches but not null

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause

Hi I use this query to get some data where imdbnumber and tmdbnumber are not both null or empty:

```
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN reviewVote="5.0" THEN reviewVote END) as count5,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN reviewVote="4.0" THEN reviewVote END) as count4,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN reviewVote="3.0" THEN reviewVote END) as count3,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN reviewVote="2.0" THEN reviewVote END) as count2,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN reviewVote="1.0" THEN reviewVote END) as count1,  COUNT(id) as totalReviews
FROM mediaReviews
WHERE imdbnumber = "tt0322259" OR tmdbnumber = ""
```

I think that this: `WHERE imdbnumber = "tt0322259" OR tmdbnumber = ""` is wrong.
I want that this query return value where `imdbnumber` or `tmdbnumber` matches but `imdbnumber` and `tmdbnumber` must not match if is empty.

Thanks

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  What might be empty?

Answer (score 1):

First, you can simplify the logic using `SUM()`:

```
SELECT SUM( reviewVote = '5.0') as count5,
       SUM( reviewVote = '4.0') as count4,
       SUM( reviewVote = '3.0') as count3,
       SUM( reviewVote = '2.0') as count2,
       SUM( reviewVote = '1.0') as count1,
       COUNT(*) as totalReviews
FROM mediaReviews mr;
```

Then for the `WHERE` clause.  If `tmdbnumber` is being passed in as a parameter, then:

```
WHERE mr.imdbnumber = tmdbnumber or tmdbnumber IS NULL
```

Or, you might want either to match a constant:

```
WHERE 'tt0322259' IN (mr.imdbnumber, mr.tmdbnumber)
```

This will not match "empty" values, so you have nothing to worry about.

If it is a column then you only want rows where these match:

```
WHERE mr.imdbnumber = mr.tmdbnumber
```

Your question is not clear on which is the case.

Comment: my problem is... if imbdnumber is null check with tmdbnumber or if tmdbnumber is null check with imdbnumber. Now I solved with 2 "if" inside my script.

Comment: @TheCesco1988 . . . The `IN` version will work in that case.